# Unittest (sometimes) fails because floating-point imprecision

Tags: python, unit-testing, floating-point

I have a class *Vector* that represents a point in 3-dimensional space. This vector has a method `normalize(self, length = 1)` which scales the vector down/up to be `length == vec.normalize(length).length`.

The unittest for this method **sometimes** fails because of the imprecision of floating-point numbers. My question is, how can I make sure this test does not fail when the methods are implemented correctly? Is it possible to do it ***without*** testing for an approximate value?

---

**Additional information**:

```
    def testNormalize(self):
        vec = Vector(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
        self.assertEqual(vec.normalize(5).length, 5)
```

This ***sometimes*** results in either `AssertionError: 4.999999999999999 != 5` or `AssertionError: 5.000000000000001 != 5`.

*Note*: I am aware that the floating-point issue may be in the `Vector.length` property or in `Vector.normalize()`.

Comment: try rounding it to less decimal places

Comment: @JBernardo: That's bad advice -- small differences in the original values can still result in the rounded values being different.

Comment: round() also does different things in python 2.x vs 3.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior and http://python-future.org/future-builtins.html?highlight=round

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### 1) How can I make sure the test works?

Use `assertAlmostEqual`, `assertNotAlmostEqual`.

From the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual):

```
assertAlmostEqual(first, second, places=7, msg=None, delta=None)
```

*Test that first and second are approximately equal by computing the difference, rounding to the given number of decimal places (default 7), and comparing to zero.*

#### 2) Is it possible to do it without testing for an approximate value?

Esentially No.

The [floating point issue](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) can't be bypassed, so you have either to "round" the result given by `vec.normalize` or accept an almost-equal result (each one of the two is an approximation).

Comment: Sure, but the OP is specifically asking if it can be done "**without** testing for an approximate value" (emphasis theirs).

Comment: @aix: But it is the nicest answer under the ones that recommend using an approximate comparison. I will just check out the approach of jcollado, but I think I will fall back to this method as the `decimal.Decimal` approach seems to be impractical.

Comment: @aix: he asked if it's possible without an approximation, and the answer to that is no, because from one side or the other he have to deal with the representation of a floating point.

Comment: (+1) Fair enough. I see that the answer has undergone significant editing since I made that remark.

Comment: Perfect answer, especially after your edit. :) +1, check-marked.

Comment: @NiklasR: Thanks! I'm fairly new to SO, so a compliment like yours means a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

By using a floating point value, you accept a small possible imprecision.  Therefore, your tests should test if your computed value falls in an acceptable range such as:

```
theoreticalValue - epsilon < normalizedValue < theoreticalValue + epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is a very small value that you define as acceptable for a variation due to floating point imprecision.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one possibility is to apply the function to test cases for which all inputs, the results of all intermediate calculations, and the output are exactly representable by `float`.

To illustrate:

```
In [2]: import math

In [4]: def norm(x, y):
   ...:     return math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
   ...: 

In [6]: norm(3, 4) == 5
Out[6]: True
```

Not sure how practical this is though...

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not assert equality for floats. Instead, ensure that the result is within certain bounds, e.g.:

```
self.assertTrue(abs(vec.normalize(5).length - 5) < 0.001)
```

Comment: Warning: this can raise weird exceptions like _"AssertionError: False is not true"_!