# python unittest fail caused by rounding error

Tags: python, unit-testing, rounding

I build the class for geometric transformation. When I run a Unit test it fails because of rounding errors coming from the operations inside my methods.

In my test I compare the result from one of the method which should return the point (2,2,0), but because of rounding errors it returns (1.9999999999999996, 1.9999999999999996, 0.0)

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

** DEBUG_45 from the method point=(1.9999999999999996, 1.9999999999999996, 0.0)
======================================================================
FAIL: testPointCoord (vectOper.test.TestNearestPoint.TestNearestPoint)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\src\vectOper\test\TestNearestPoint.py", line 14, in testPointCoord
self.assertEqual(pointCoord, (2,2,0), "nearest point failed")
AssertionError: nearest point failed

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

From the calculation point of view it is acceptable, but I don't want my code to fail on the simple unit test.

```
import unittest
from vectOper.nearestPoint import NearestPoint

class TestNearestPoint(unittest.TestCase):

    def testPointCoord(self):
        nearestPoint = NearestPoint()
        pointCoord = nearestPoint.pointCoord(samplePoint=(2,2,2),lineStart=(0,0,0), lineVect=(1,1,0))
        self.assertEqual(pointCoord, (2,2,0), "nearest point failed")
```

What is a correct way to resolve problem like that? Obviously I cannot round up the output numbers or convert them to integers as normally it is not the case.
Is there a way to code unit test to ignore rounding error? 
Is there any other way to resolve problem?

Edit:
The question can be solved by using `self.assertAlmostEqual` as rightly suggested in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929005/unittest-sometimes-fails-because-floating-point-imprecision) answer but the problem is that I need to test entrance of a tuple. After all suggestions I try to do:

```
def testPointCoord(self):
    nearestPoint = NearestPoint()
    pointCoord = nearestPoint.pointCoord(samplePoint=(2,2,2),lineStart=(0,0,0), lineVect=(1,1,0))
    self.assertAlmostEqual(pointCoord[0], 2, places=7, msg="nearest point x-coodr failed")
    self.assertAlmostEqual(pointCoord[1], 2, places=7, msg="nearest point y-coodr failed")
    self.assertAlmostEqual(pointCoord[2], 0, places=7, msg="nearest point z-coodr failed")
```

but I need to automatise it somehow as later I need to test a list of tuples as the sample points' coordinates for a vector field.

The solution suggested as a duplicate is only a half measure as it would be a bit tedious write 300 more comparisons if there is 100 tuples in the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unittest (sometimes) fails because floating-point imprecision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929005/unittest-sometimes-fails-because-floating-point-imprecision)

Comment: (Note that `assertAlmostEqual` doesn't have any magic to compare tuples so you need to test each of the 3 coordinates separately)

Comment: As far as I understand using assertRaises as suggested in "possible duplicate" will raise and exceptions for acceptable numbers like in case I showed and for unacceptable numbers, far away from truth. I don't think it would solve the proble

Comment: @tomasz74: I don't see any use of `assertRaises` in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Wooble thanks, I followed a link on top, it get me to another answer but now it point to the same, sorry for that. I try to figure out `assertAlmostEqual` with application to elements of tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use assertAlmostEqual in each dimension using map?
I don`t have access to your class, so i wrote a similar example here:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Test_Tuple_Equality(TestCase):
    def test_tuple_equality_True(self):
        p1 = (0.00000001, 0.00000000001, 0)
        p2 = (0,0,0)
        map(lambda x, y: self.assertAlmostEqual(x,y), p1, p2)

    def test_tuple_equality_False(self):
        p1 = (0.00000001, 0.00000000001, 0)
        p2 = (1,0,0)
        map(lambda x, y: self.assertAlmostEqual(x,y), p1, p2)
```

Map will transform your a n-dimension tuple comparisson into n floats comparissons.

You can even create a compare_points function, like:

```
def compare_points(self, p1, p2):
    map(lambda x,y: self.assertAlmostEqual(x,y), p1,p2)
```

And then use it in your tests

Another solution is to use numpy`s method for that:

```
import numpy

>>>numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal((2,2,0), (1.9999999999,2,0), decimal=7, err_msg='', verbose=True)
```

Numpy is a pain to install, but, if you already use it, it would be the best fit.

Comment: I try to implement the above, but the code gives and error, do you know where the error coming from?

    `map(lambda x, y: self.assertAlmostEqual(x,y, "nearest point failed"), p1, p2)`    
    `File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 552, in assertAlmostEqual`
    `if round(abs(second-first), places) == 0:`
`TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index`

Comment: It works for me here. Are you sure that p1 and p2 are tuples?
Try to iterate through them, as p1[0], p2[1], ...

Comment: I tried, I used also exactly your code, and I have this error. The `numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal()` works perfectly. 
I use python 2.7 on windows 7

Comment: Thanks, I should figure it out. It is strange, but it accept the message if it is as a key arg `map(lambda x, y: self.assertAlmostEqual(x,y, msg='msg'), p1, p2)`